# deploy directly from Bitbucket to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, github, bitbucket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How do I deploy my latest bits (in this case a nodejs app) from Bitbucket to the AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

I want to avoid doing a git aws.push from my local system since that pushes the entire repo which can be painfully slow in low bandwidth scenarios.

What I would like is to be able to commit my changes locally then push to Bitbucket. Then trigger a deployment from Bitbucket to the Elastic Beanstalk deployment.

any help would be appreciated. I'd love to avoid having to sign up for a third party service just to do this but if that's necessary, I'd welcome recommendations

Comment: what did you end up doing to get this to work?  I'm in the same boat.

Answer (score 4):

Only the first git aws.push is full. All the others are incremental.

However, it poses an interesting question. Here are a few ideas:

- Host your own CI/CD service, like Jenkins or Drone (FWIW, I wrote the [Jenkins AWSEB Deployment Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/AWSEB+Deployment+Plugin)
- Use a cloud service. I recommend [Codeship](http://codeship.io) (free), but [Drone.io](http://drone.io) and [Travis](http://travis-ci.org) (free for Public Projects) are also good picks
- Write a Bitbucket Hook to do it itself, and host on [Iron.io](http://iron.io) (like I incidentally made with [mirrormirror-go](https://bitbucket.org/aldrinleal/mirrormirror-go)

Answer (score 1):

Today (2020) The answer is well outdated. Bitbucket pipelines exists today and there are fairly good documentations on this:

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/deploy-to-aws-with-elastic-beanstalk/

Comment: looks like the entire zip is still being uploaded. check the ZIP_FILE mandatory parameter.